# pyspark calculate quartiles based on ID and classify based on the quartile ranges

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark 1.5.2. I have a pyspark dataframe with column "ID" and "Height" as shown below:

```
|           ID1|           ID2|       height|
---------------------------------------------
|             1|           000|           44|
|             2|           000|         72.9|
|             3|           000|           89|
|             4|           000|         45.5|
|             5|           000|         52.3|
|             6|           000|         87.9|
|             7|           000|         63.1|
|             8|           000|         26.1|
|             9|           000|           97|
|            10|           000|          120|
|            11|           000|           99|
|            12|           000|           96|
|            13|           000|         36.5|
|            14|           000|            0|
|            15|           001|           48|
|            16|           001|        152.1|
|            17|           001|         72.2|
|            18|           001|         21.5|
|            19|           001|           94|
|            20|           001|          220|
+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I want to calculate the quartiles of height for each "ID2" and classify them as tall, medium or short based on the following criteria:

```
Short: All height < Q1
Medium: All height within inclusive inter-quartile range (IQR) Q3-Q1
Tall: All height > Q3
```

I was looking into the pyspark.sql module and found a summary() function with which I can calculate the quartile ranges but it doesn't work with groupby based on the column "ID2". The ultimate result would be:

```
|       ID1 |     Height |
-------------------------
|          1|        Tall|
|          2|       Short|
|          3|      Medium|  and so on
```

How can I do this? Is there a better approach or easier way?

I am fairly new to this and would appreciate any help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your input dataframe in the process function and it will return back the output dataframe as intended by the author.
The quantile function returns both the values present under the range and plugs back to the original dataframe. And then one can run the comparator on the top.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def quantile(x):
    x['first']= np.percentile(x['height'], 25)
    x['third']= np.percentile(x['height'], 75)
    return  x

def process(input_df):
    grouped_df = input_df.groupby(['ID2']).apply(quantile)
    grouped_df.loc[(grouped_df.height >= grouped_df.first) & (grouped_df.height <= grouped_df.third), 'result'] = 'Medium'
    grouped_df.loc[(grouped_df.height < grouped_df.first) , 'result'] = 'Short'
    grouped_df.loc[ (grouped_df.height > grouped_df.third),'result'] = 'Tall'
    return grouped_df


main_df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
print process(main_df)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach without pandas using pyspark 1.5.2. "input_df" is the original dataframe here:

```
input_df.registerTempTable("input_df")
quartile_df = sqlContext.sql("select id2, percentile_approx(cast(height as decimal), 0.25) as Q1_value, percentile_approx(cast(height as decimal), 0.5) as Q2_value, percentile_approx(cast(height as decimal), 0.75) as Q3_value from input_df group by id2")
input_df=input_df.join(quartile_df, input_df.id2 == quartile_df.id2, 'left_outer')
input_df.select(F.when(input_df.height < input_df.Q1_value, 'short').when(input_df.height.between(input_df.Q1_value, input_df.Q3_value), 'medium').when(input_df.height > input_df.Q3_value, 'tall').alias('height_tag')).show()
```

The code above basically registers the input_df as a temporary table and allows querying through SQL. In the query, using percentile_approx gives a Q1, Q2 and Q3 with 25%, 50% and 75% respectively which is ultimately joined with original dataframe. In the final LOC, each value of "height" is classified as short, medium or tall based on the condition.

Hope this helps